# sys.settrace seems to be ignored in threads

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging

So I started working on an experimental debugger that attempts to solve a few issue that I have as I'm mainly debugging stuff located on remote machines.

Here's an example of the code I have:

```
debugger = threading.local()
debugger.instance = None
        
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Debugger(object):
    ...
    def __call__(self, frame, event, arg):
        thread_name = threading.current_thread().getName()
        _logger.debug(
            "Start Trace (%s) %s %s",
            thread_name,
            event,
            arg
        )
        ...
    


def set_trace():
    _logger.debug("[%s] Set trace", threading.current_thread().getName())
    thread_name = threading.current_thread().getName()

    try:
        instance = debugger.instance
        if not instance:
            debugger.instance = Debugger()
            instance = debugger.instance
    except Exception:
        debugger.instance = Debugger()
        instance = debugger.instance

    def destroy(instance):
        def wrap():
            _logger.debug("[%s] Destroying debugger instance", thread_name)
            instance.stop()
        return wrap

    atexit.register(destroy(instance))

    if not instance.stopped:
        _logger.debug("[%s] Set trace to %s", thread_name, instance)
        sys.settrace(instance)
    else:
        _logger.debug("[%s] Remove trace", thread_name)
        sys.settrace(None)
```

And the code of the program:

```
import sys
from threading import Thread
from threading import get_ident
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')

value = 2

def start_job():
    print("In thread", get_ident())
    import d2
    d2.set_trace()
    # breakpoint()                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    print("In thread value", value)
    print("End thread", get_ident())

thread = Thread(target=start_job, args=tuple())
thread.start()
```

And here's a log of what I got:

```
....
In thread 139757304022784
DEBUG:d2:[Thread-1] Set trace
DEBUG:d2:[Thread-1] Waiting for the client from the async thread
DEBUG:d2:[Thread-1] Set trace to <d2.Debugger object at 0x7f1bc877fe80>
In thread value 2
End thread 139757304022784
....
```

The first line in this log is from set_trace and the second line is from the constructor of debugger. The third line is right before sys.settrace has the debugger set.
In thread value 2 is the line after the set_trace call and the last line is pretty much the last line of the thread itself.

The thing is that for MainThread it works flawlessly and I can actually see logs like those:

```
DEBUG:d2:Start Trace (MainThread) call None
DEBUG:d2:Start Trace (MainThread) line None
DEBUG:d2:Start Trace (MainThread) line None
DEBUG:d2:Start Trace (MainThread) call None
DEBUG:d2:Start Trace (MainThread) line None
```

But the calls made to settrace seems to be completely ignored. I also tried to use `threading.settrace` and it seems to be working more or less. It will start debugging the threads but in reality I don't want to trace the whole thread but only wherever I'd put a breakpoint.

Eventually I'd like to be able to do `sys.settrace(None)` to disable tracing and have a breakpoint enable the debugger back if needed.

Edit: I think I found the reason for this behaviour in this question. [Does "sys.settrace" work properly in Python 3.5 but not in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932655/does-sys-settrace-work-properly-in-python-3-5-but-not-in-python-3-6)

> The trace function is invoked (with event set to 'call') whenever a new local scope is entered; it should return a reference to a local trace function to be used for the new scope, or None if the scope shouldn’t be traced.

So apparently, it won't start tracing right after settrace but only after a new localscope is created after calling settrace().

Comment: "So apparently, it won't start tracing right after settrace but only after a new localscope is created after calling settrace()." - yeah, you need to set the `f_trace` attribute on a frame object if you want to turn on tracing in an existing frame.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/bdb.py#L330 I just realized that's all I have to do. It works. I guess it makes sense, only new frame will receive the new trace function while old frame will keep the one they add. The behaviour is a bit like threading.settrace which is a default for new threads.  I didn't realize it was a feature of the frame and not a "state" of the interpreter.